# Magento 2 How to override configurable.phml file in custom module

Tags: magento2, layout, template-override

I have tried below way to override configurable.phtml file

1. /app/code/Vendor/Extension/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view_type_configurable.xml

https://i.imgur.com/gpII3Ct.png

But it did not override if I change constant value on below file path it's work for me.

/vendor/magento/module-swatches/Block/Product/Renderer/Configurable.php

On this file apply changes const CONFIGURABLE_RENDERER_TEMPLATE = 'Magento_ConfigurableProduct::product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml'; to const CONFIGURABLE_RENDERER_TEMPLATE = 'Vendor_Extension::product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml';

So, override phtml file I also create preferences this file for change constant value but it also not work for me.

So How to override this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to override **SetTemplate** or **toHtml** function using plugin or alternative is to override **getRendererTemplate** function using preferences. From below file

```
/vendor/magento/module-swatches/Block/Product/Renderer/Configurable.php
```